# Perl: find values to all form fields in a webpage

Tags: perl, mechanize

My current program can print all forms in a webpage with name of fields, i want to print current values also.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$m->get("http://www.rediff.com/");
@arr   = $m->forms;
$count = 1;
foreach (@arr) {
    my @inputfields = $_->param;
    print "form $count fields are:\n";
    $count++;
    foreach (@inputfields) {
        print "$_\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

output:

```
form 1 fields are:
srchword
src

form 2 fields are:
login
passwd
remember
seclogin
FormName
```

Expected:
i want to display values also, like

```
login : abc@rediff.com
```

Comment: What values? The login field on that page doesn't have a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$form->value` method as documented in [`HTML::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Form):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$m->get("http://www.rediff.com/");
my $count = 1;
for my $form ($m->forms) {
    print "form $count fields are:\n";
    $count++;
    for ($form->param) {
        printf "%s - %s\n", $_, $form->value($_);
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
form 1 fields are:
srchword - 
src - web

form 2 fields are:
login - 
passwd - 
remember - 1
seclogin - on
FormName - existing
```

Comment: like you used $form-value($_), will $form->name($_) and $form->id($_) work. What all other info can i get this way other than values.

Comment: Just read the documentation for [`HTML::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Form).  That's how I discovered how to find the values.  It will do a much better job of detailing the features that are available then any comment here.